# INSERT new row or DELETE old row IF it already exists using laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am assigning multiple skills to an employee using **checkboxes**. when a user checks the **checkbox** a new record is inserted into pivot table. if a user unchecks the **checkbox** a record is deleted.

Now i am wondering if there is any function for insert or delete like there exists for new insert or update which is **updateOrCreate** to update an existing record or create a new record if none exists.

**I can do it the hard way. but just want to know if there is any function for this like updateOrCreate.**

Comment: let me know if the if it's not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `sync` method it will replace the old values to new.

`$employee->skill()->sync($request->checkedSkill)`